# How to increase and update the int two functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to increase an int value on button click, but it's value doesn't update in another function.

```
Public class example: MonoBehavior{
int x = 0;

  void Update(){
     Debug.Log(x); //x = 0
  }

  //Functions called in unity button click
  void UIBtnClicked(){
     x++;
     Debug.Log(x); //x = 1
  }

}
```

Comment: I suspect the instance on which `Update` is called is a different instance than the one that `UIBtnClicked` is called on.

Comment: Is it the same instance of the `example` class or is a new object of the class created between button clicks and calls to `Update`?

Comment: Where is `Update` called from? Since this isn't derived from `MomoBehaviour` it won't be called automatically. With the typo it won't even compile.

Comment: It inherited a MonoBehaviour

Comment: Are you sure the UIBtnClicked is being run?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, it runs

Comment: maybe have other script to reset "x" this value ?

Comment: Are you sure "x" only aseet value by `UIBtnClicked` ?

Comment: maybe you have two Gameobject, and you print other gameobject value. not the one you called.

Comment: You mention not in another function. What other function

Answer (score 0):

If the class isn't inherited from MonoBehaviour, it is just a regular function. Won't behave like and Update in a MonoBehaviour.

Comment: It does, I just forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty object on scene with tag ( tag : "emptyObject" etc.) ,
Then you can add a script on this empty object with int prop.

```
Public class XController: MonoBehavior{
  public int x = 0;
}
```

Then you can find this empty object from tag and increase or decrease x value like this.

```
Public class example: MonoBehavior{
    private XController xController;

    void Start(){
      emptyGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("emptyObject").GetComponent<XController>();
    }
    
    void Update(){
      Debug.Log(xController.x); //x = 0
    }

    //Functions called in unity button click
    void UIBtnClicked(){
      xController.x++;
      Debug.Log(xController.x); //x = 1
    }
}
```

You can always reach the **same instance** of xController and change the value.

Answer (score 0):

That's maybe because the reference to the UIButtonClicked is missing.
Try adding public before UIButtonClicked like this:

```
public void UIBtnClicked(){
     x++;
     Debug.Log(x); //x = 1   
}
```

And then reassign this script again to that button like this:
[image]